Understanding of evanescent waves and far field spatial resolution limit
This might be a lengthy thread because of several unclear concepts, all related to each-other when discussing wave optics.
In our class we described what the evanescent waves are. The example considered limits my ability to have a general understanding of what these waves are and how do they differ from propagating waves, to an intuitive level, primarily because the explanation is based on a specific case and not a general case, so it is hard for me to generalize the phenomenon of evanescent waves. I will describe what we discussed and hopefully someone can help me understand, on an intuitive and physical level the difference between evanescent and propagating waves.
I will start by saying that I know that the main difference between the two is that evanescent waves are damped while propagating ones, as the name suggest, propagate. What I don't understand is how and what causes this different behavior.
We considered the following two cases:
1 - $k_z=\sqrt{k^2 -k_x^2-k_y^2}$ being real. This is a plane propagating wave.
2 - $k_z=\sqrt{k^2 -k_x^2-k_y^2}$ being imaginary. This is an exponentially decaying wave, an evanescent wave.
It is important to mention at this point, that from the above equations, one can comment on the nature of a wave (propagating or evanescent) only after knowing the relationship among the wavevector components. And to be honest, I can't really describe with words the physical interpretation of the 2nd equation. What I mean by this is i.e in the first equation we are just finding the z component of $\vec k$ with  Pythagoras rule. And one can visualize what is taking place here and can sketch it. For the 2nd equation I don't know what to sketch and how to visualize a case in which a component is negative?
I have several questions here.

Does it mean, in the case when the term is imaginary, that alongside x and y, the wave is propagating but not in the z direction?

How can one give a geometrical representation of the wavevector $\vec k$ in the case of evanescent waves?

If we consider two waves, both propagating nearly in the z direction, where one is evanescent. Now from what I can understand for the propagating wave, each component is smaller than the wavenumber, while for the evanescent one the components are larger? How does one visually represent this difference ?

Can there be an evanescent wave in all the spatial dimensions?


And then the following is said:
Therefore ,only spatial frequencies $k<\frac{2\pi n}{\lambda}$ propagate.
If one were to interpret this condition, basically for different waves of different k-values, only those with spatial frequencies smaller than some arbitrary value $\frac{2\pi n}{\lambda}$ are allowed to propagate. But this condition makes no sense when you have in mind the conditions described above. The difference is pretty evident. Above we compare components of a wave with each other in order to make a statement for the nature of the wave, while here we are comparing the wavenumbers of different waves with a cut-off value. It makes no sense. What am I missing here?
For this upcoming part I could make a new thread, but the content of it is tied to what was discussed above:
If we are in the case of the far field resolution limit. This means that the evanescent waves are not present, as they would have damped out.
Now the condition for the propagation is : All spatial frequencies that can propagate need to be smaller than $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}n$
We have a bandwidth of spatial frequencies $\Delta K_T<\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}n$
We have a bandwidth in position space $\Delta r_T$.
From the condition $\Delta K_T\Delta r_T>1$ one gets that:
the min$\Delta r_T=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi n}$ this is the smallest possible localization of the wave. The ultimately one can write:
min$\Delta r_T =\frac{\lambda}{2\pi NA}$
How do we derive this formula?
